# MySQL drop table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-drop

I want to drop a table with `drop table EMPLOYEE;`

but I get the error: `#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

I looked around on the internet to show the hidden constraints and found:

```
CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEE` (
`Ssn` int(9) NOT NULL,
`Dno` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY`Ssn_8` (`Ssn`),
UNIQUE KEY`Dno_13` (`Dno`),
CONSTRAINT `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY(`Dno`) REFERENCES `DEPARTMENT` (`Dnumber`),
CONSTRAINT `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY(`Dno`) REFERENCES `DEPARTMENT` (`Dnumber`),
CONSTRAINT `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY(`Dno`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`Dno`),
CONSTRAINT `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY(`Dno`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`Dno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1




   CREATE TABLE `DEPARTMENT` (
`Dnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Mgr_ssn` int(9) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY`Mgr_ssn` (`Mgr_ssn`),
UNIQUE KEY`Dnumber` (`Dnumber`),
CONSTRAINT `DEPARTMENT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY(`Mgr_ssn`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`Ssn`),
CONSTRAINT `DEPARTMENT_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY(`Mgr_ssn`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`Ssn`),
CONSTRAINT `DEPARTMENT_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY(`Mgr_ssn`) REFERENCES `DEPARTMENT` (`Mgr_ssn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

After finding this I tried  dropping the contraints first with:
`alter table EMPLOYEE drop contraint 'EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1';`

but I keep getting:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1'' at line 1`

I have worked at dropping this table for several hours now and searched many topics on the internet. People ended up dropping the db, but I am unauthorized to drop db or create a db.

Comment: Looks like you misspelled 'constraint' in your ALTER...DROP statement, if you truly copied and pasted.

Comment: I misspelled that when typing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First remove the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints from `DEPARTMENT` to `EMPLOYEE` (note the weird syntax, you should use `DROP FOREIGN KEY` but with the constraint(!) identifier):

```
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT
  DROP  FOREIGN KEY  DEPARTMENT_ibfk_1 ,
  DROP  FOREIGN KEY  DEPARTMENT_ibfk_2 ;
```

Then drop the `EMPLOYEE` table:

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE ;
```

---

The problem with your code was that you used `DROP CONSTRAINT` - which is correct, AFAIK it is the standard SQL syntax for `ALTER TABLE`.

MySQL however, "prefers" `DROP FOREIGN KEY`. In other words, it doesn't comply with standards in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code allowed me to drop both tables. Could I ask what is the difference between this code and what I was doing before? Is it because it is dropping both keys in the same statement?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key names need to be quoted with backticks:

```
alter table EMPLOYEE drop constraint `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1`;
                                     ^               ^
```

using `'` single quotes turns that into just a string.

Comment: I still get the same error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1`' at line 1

Comment: Yes because you need to remove the foreign key constraint in the departments table first

Comment: No, identifiers need to be quoted, only if they are reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the foreign keys in table Employee and also the foregin keys to table employee from  Department and then try to drop it.

**NOTE**: Need to drop the foreign keys of the table being referenced first in the department table.

Also remove any references from Department to Employee in the Department table first.

Comment: How would I go about do that? I have also tried: alter table EMPLOYEE drop `Ssn_8`;

Comment: do that in Department table first, drop the foreign key constraint of employee table there

Comment: I just tried that on the Department table as well, but get the same error. Am i suppose to try and drop the constraint or the actually key?

Comment: I get error: #1025 - Error on rename of './leal@002ddb/#sql-392_7d0fe' to './leal@002ddb/DEPARTMENT' (errno: 150)   when dropping the key itself and get error #1064 when i try and drop the constraint

Comment: Ok do a few things here, I see you are referencing foreign keys within the same table EMPLOYEE_ibfk_3 and EMPLOYEE_ibfk_4. Remove those first, then the department ones ** Dont drop the key.. there is no need, just the contraints

Comment: Ok, I just tried removing EMPLOYEE_ibfk_3 and EMPLOYEE_ibfk_4 as well as the two from Departments table, but i keep getting error 1064, this is what i typed in: alter table EMPLOYEE drop constraint `EMPLOYEE_ibfk_3`;

Comment: Are there any constraints in the department table to employee? You have to check that there arent any other tables referencing Employee table.

Comment: I just updated my original post with the department table as well

Comment: OK TRY THIS, for both tables alter the tables to do this 

                    FOREIGN KEY (blah) REFERENCES BLAH(BLAh)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE "NOTICE THE ON DELETE CASCADE"  ......Then try to drop the constraints**

Comment: Thanks for sticking with my problem thus far. I have tried copying your code and running it, but I still get error 1064